# Warn new users on 20-minute question delay limit after first question, not against second question

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, new-users, rate-limiting, warning

I got the very annoying warning below after fighting to submit a question and having it refused for unintentionally trying to add new tags.

1. Should post this warning during the 20 minute period starting from the first question that started the clock, not after s/he's worked 5 minutes writing the question and has to save it in Notepad for later or tomorrow
2. In the message, link the words "new user" to a definition of "new user"

> Oops! Your question couldn't be
>   submitted because: new users can only
>   post questions every 20 minutes; try
>   again later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be easy to check the same conditions when asking a question rather than submitting the question. It would be even cooler to put a count-down timer on the question writing page.

Comment: Yes, a timer, with a randomly-changing half-serious suggestion of what to do instead of submitting another question so quickly. Invite you to browse around on the site, or get a cup a joe, or ...

Answer (score 1):

This was basically a bug that was fixed many months ago; errors in submission aren't treated as a valid question submission any more.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this optimistic warning rather than pessimistic... most users will not try to submit multiple questions so quick so the processing is left till someone tries.  Save the cycles!